# Windows Server 2008 standard edition vs. Windows Server 2008 Enterprise edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am developing (using C# + VSTS 2008 + IIS 7.0 + SQL Server 2008 Express edition + ASP.Net + x64) a web application, small scale (at most 1000 users and at most 20 concurrent users on the web site, and database size within 1G bytes).

I am selecting whether to use Windows Server 2008 standard edition or Windows Server 2008 Enterprise edition. Any suggestions for my situation? Any special limitations of standard edition in my scenario which needs to take care of?

BTW: if standard edition is enough, I will use standard edition to save cost.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't need Enterprise just to host a website.  Standard would be fine.  But if all you're doing is hosting a web site, why not go with Server 2008 Web Edition for even less money.  Here's a [comparison of the different editions](http://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/sample/DOMIS/update/2008/02feb/0208ws2plp_ch.htm).

Comment: Cool, question answered!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the x64 standard edition. The main advantages of the enterprise edition is scalability, which you probably won't need for the loads you describe.